# Running batch file on command prompt but facing error

Tags: batch-file

I am running my batch file through command prompt but facing issue that "failed to register URL" below is screen shot:

[image]
Here is the code for batch file which I'm running:

```
SET EX="C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe"

if not "%1" == "" (
    CALL %EX% /path:%CD% /port:%1
) else (
    CALL %EX% /path:%CD%
)
```

How can I resolve this issue? I haven't found any solution so far, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the script like this and invoke it from the site folder. *(it uses `%~dp0` for the `/Path` so in this specific case the script would be in `C:\sample`)*

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "_="
If /I Not "%CD%"=="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\IIS Express" (Set "_=T"
    PushD "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\IIS Express" 2>Nul || GoTo :EOF)

If Not "%~1"=="" (Set "opts=/Port:%1") Else Set "opts="

IISExpress /Path:"%~dp0" %opts%
If Defined _ PopD
```

I'm not sure that `CALL`ing `iisexpress.exe` is appropriate in this case, but feel free to use it if it's omission causes issues. Give this script a try and report back as necessary.